# How do add complex text using vim/sed/awk

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk, sed, vim

following older posts ([How do I use vim on the command line to add text to the middle of a file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/162345/how-do-i-use-vim-on-the-command-line-to-add-text-to-the-middle-of-a-file) & [How to insert the content of a file into another file before a pattern (marker)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32908/how-to-insert-the-content-of-a-file-into-another-file-before-a-pattern-marker)), I have a more complex case which I need your advice.
I have the following Test.conf file:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  jenkins2;

    location /DE06/ {
        proxy_pass     http://jenkins2:18015/DE06/;
    }
}
```

I want to run one command, so in the end, the file content will be:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  jenkins2;

    location /DE15/ {
        proxy_pass     http://jenkins2:18015/DE15/;
    }

    location /DE06/ {
        proxy_pass     http://jenkins2:52716/DE06/;
    }
}
```

means I need to find the first occurrence of the word jenkins2, and then add this content:

```
location /DE15/ {
    proxy_pass     http://jenkins2:18015/DE15/;
}
```

any idea what is the right command?

Comment: This would be better asked in [Vi and Vim Stack Exchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Does the answer have to use vim? While it's an editor, there are other ways of updating files programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

`vim +/jenkins2 +j +":r insert.txt" +gg=G +wq testfile.txt`

where insert.txt contains the snippet you want to add and testfile.txt is the file you want do edit.

I'm not sure vim is the best tool to do that, though.

- `+/jenkins2` search for jenkins2
- `+j` move down one line
- `":r insert.txt"` read the file to insert. Mind the quotes!
- `+gg=G` autoindent the file
- `+wq` and write it

Answer (score 0):

I've found a working sed command:

```
sed -i -e '/jenkins5/{ r example.txt' -e '; :L; n; bL;}' nginx_jenkins.conf
```

When env param is needed, you can use:

```
sed -i -e '/'${Alias}'/{ r example.txt' -e '; :L; n; bL;}' nginx_jenkins.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

For fun and learning, as a vimgolf on your example, there is this

```
vim +"4t4|/D/,/}/t4|'[,s/06/15/|s/52716/18015/|x" file.conf
```

Commands are separated by `|` :

- `4t4` copy line 4 on line 4
- `/D/,/}/t4` from line containing the first `D` to line containing the next `}`, copy on line 4
- `'[,s/06/15/` from the first line of the last change to current line (last line of the last change), substitute `06` by `15`
- `s/52716/18015/` substitute on current line (where `06` was last substituted)
- `x` save changes and exit

[`:h :copy`](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#:copy),
[`:h '[`](https://vimhelp.org/motion.txt.html#'[),
[`:h :/`](https://vimhelp.org/cmdline.txt.html#:/)